# Available metrics behind Sharing

Tags: sharepoint-online, share

SharePoint Online - Can anyone advise if there is a way to see often the Sharing Feature has been used?  I've seen nothing in the OOB reporting that seems to capture this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Security and Compliance Center will track this for you.

- In the app launcher, go to Security and Compliance
- Click Search & Investigation
- Click Audit log search
- Click the activities dropdown and select your desired actions[image]
- Specify a desired date range and or sites and click Search

Comment: The "why did I not think about this" thought just strikes me.  Appreciate the detailed response.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: No worries, we all have those moments :)